# C - Passing a 3D arrays of chars to a function

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a program that analyzes a (3 x 4) matrix of strings provided by the user.  Ultimately, it needs to output the longest string present in the matrix, along with that string's length.

My program seems to read the input correctly, as judged its success in echoing back the input strings, but it does not correctly output the longest word. I'm sure I'm committing some kind of pointer-related error when I pass the value of longest word, but I do not have any idea how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M 4
#define N 5
#define MAX_DIM 20

void findMAX(char matrice[N][M][MAX_DIM]) {
   char maxr;
   int index;
   int i, j, it;

   index = 0;
   maxr = *(*(*(matrice+0)+0)+MAX_DIM);

   for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < M-1; j++) {
         if (index < strlen(matrice[i][j])) {
            index = strlen(matrice[i][j]);

            // I save the longer line's value            
            it = i;

            // I save the maximum's value
            maxr = *(*(*(matrice+i)+j)+MAX_DIM);
         }
      }
   }

   printf ("The MAX is: -/%s/- and it's long: -/%d/- \n", maxr, index);
   printf ("It is content in the: %d line, which is: \n", it);
   for (j = 0; j < N-1; j++) {
        printf("%s  ", matrice[it][j]);
   }
}

void leggi(char matrice[N][M][MAX_DIM]) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M-1; j++) {
            printf ("Insert the element matrix [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf  ("%s", matrice[i][j]); 
            fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
}

void stampa(char matrice[N][M][MAX_DIM]) {
    int i, j;

    printf("\n(4 x 3) MATRIX\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M-1; j++) {
            printf("%s ", matrice[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char matrix[N][M][MAX_DIM]; //Matrix of N*M strings, which are long MAX_DIM

    printf("************************************************\n");
    printf("**   FIND THE LINE WITH THE MAXIMUM ELEMENT   **\n");
    printf("**            IN A (4 x 3) MATRIX             **\n");
    printf("************************************************\n");

    printf ("Matrix Reading & Printing\n");
    leggi  (matrix);
    stampa (matrix);

    findMAX(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference **never**.

Comment: In the first place, you seem to be missing that C does not have pass by reference.  All function arguments are passed by value.  These may include pointers, but passing a pointer to a thing by value is not the same as passing the thing itself by reference.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, my mistake.Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The problem is you've probably inverted your dimensions somewhere. `Also: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]` at `printf ("The MAX is: -/%s/- and it's long: -/%d/- \n", maxr, index);`

Comment: In all of your `for` loops you've *inverted* the dimensions, the last items should be `matrice[N - 1][M - 1]` but you're trying to access something like `matrice[M - 1][N - 1]`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you! It was a BIG inadvertence by me. I edited it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, anyway?  I'm afraid we have done you a disservice by not asking that much sooner.  In what way does the program misbehave?  What input causes such a problem?  What are the expected and actual results?  Can you reduce the program to a smaller one that still demonstrates the same problem?  All of these questions are aimed at prodding you to provide a [mcve], which is our usual expectation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The problem was about `findMax` function, as I said in the question the program needs to write in output the longer word presents in the matrix. Essentially my errors were on the way for passing the value of `matrice` to `maxr`, and inverting the dimensions `N` and `M`. Next time I'll try to be more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to address some misconceptions conveyed by another answer, consider your 3D array declared as

```
char matrix[N][M][MAX_DIM];
```

, where `N`, `M`, and `MAX_DIM` are macros expanding to integer constants.

- This is an ordinary array (not a variable-length array).
- If you want to pass this array to a function, it is perfectly acceptable to declare the corresponding function parameter exactly the same way as you've declared the array, as indeed you do:

```
    void findMAX(char matrice[N][M][MAX_DIM])
```

- But it is true that what is actually passed is not the array itself, but a pointer to its first element (by which all other elements can also be accessed.  In C, multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, so the first element of a three-dimensional array is a two-dimensional array.  In any case, that function declaration is equivalent to both of these:

  ```
  void findMAX(char (*matrice)[M][MAX_DIM]) 


  void findMAX(char matrice[][M][MAX_DIM])
  ```

  Note in particular that the first dimension is not conveyed.  Of those three equivalent forms, I find the last clearest in most cases.

It is quite odd, though, the way you access array elements in your findMAX() function.  Here is the prototypical example of what you do:

```
        maxr = *(*(*(matrice+i)+j)+MAX_DIM);
```

But what an ugly and confusing expression that is, especially compared to this guaranteed-equivalent one:

```
        maxr = matrice[i][j][MAX_DIM];
```

Looking at that however, and it how you are using it, I find that although the assignment is type-correct, you are probably using the wrong type.  `maxr` holds a single `char`.  If you mean it to somehow capture the value of a whole string, then you need to declare it either as an array (into which you will copy strings' contents as needed), or as a pointer that you will set to point to the string of interest.  The latter approach is more efficient, and I see nothing to recommend the former for your particular usage.

Thus, I think you want

```
    char *maxr;
```

... and later ...

```
        maxr = matrice[0][0];
```

... and ...

```
        maxr = matrice[i][j];
```

That sort of usage should be familiar to you from, for example, your function `stampo()`; the primary difference is that now you're assigning the expression to a variable instead of passing it directly to a function.

And it turns out that changing `maxr`'s type that way will correct the real problem here, which @AnttiHaapala already pointed out in comments: this function call ...

```
    printf ("The MAX is: -/%s/- and it's long: -/%d/- \n", maxr, index);
```

requires the second argument (`maxr`) to be a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char` in order to correspond to the `%s` directive in the format string.  Before, you were passing a single `char` instead, but with this correction you should get mostly the expected result.

You will probably, however, see at least one additional anomaly.  You final loop in that function has the wrong bound.  You are iterating with `j`, which is used as an index for the second dimension of your array.  That dimension's extent is `M`, but the loop runs to `N - 1`.

Finally, I should observe that it's odd that you allocate space for a 5 x 4 array (of `char` arrays) and then ignore the last row and column.  But that's merely wasteful, not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void findMAX(char matrice[N][M][MAX_DIM]){
//   char maxr
   char maxr[MAX_DIM];
   int index;
   int i, j, it;

   index = 0;
//   maxr = *(*(*(matrice+0)+0)+MAX_DIM);
   strncpy(maxr, *(*(matrice+0)+0), MAX_DIM);

   for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < M-1; j++)
      {
         if (index < strlen(matrice[i][j]))
         {                   
            index = strlen(matrice[i][j]);
            it = i;
//            maxr = *(*(*(matrice+i)+j)+MAX_DIM);
            strncpy(maxr, *(*(matrice+i)+j), MAX_DIM);
         }
      }
   }

   printf ("The MAX is: -/%s/- and it's long: -/%d/- \n", maxr, index);
   printf ("It is content in the: %d line, which is: \n", it);
//   for (j = 0; j < N-1; j++){
   for (j = 0; j < M-1; j++){   
        printf("%s  ", matrice[it][j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: And why should he try that?  What is its advantage over the original version?  What do you claim was the problem that this version fixes?

Comment: @miraklis I tried to use `strncpy` function, but I was doing it in the wrong way since yours works smoothly. @JohnBollinger It actually solved the problems I was experiencing in output.

Comment: @John Bollinger, i commented out the parts that i thought was wrong. The main problem was that maxr wasn't an array, as i thought it should be.

Comment: Don't answer me in comments, @miraklis, improve your answer!  For what it's worth, I think it's kludgy to make `maxr` an array, but I think you may be right that its type is unsuited to its intended use.  Making it a `char *` would serve better, as there would be no need for copying strings.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible to pass multi-dimensional arrays to C functions if the size of the minor dimensions is known at compile time. However the syntax is unacceptable

```
 void foo( int (*array2d)[6] )
```

Often array dimensions aren't known at compile time and it is necessary to create a  flat array and access via

```
   array2D[y*width+x]
```

Generally it's easier just to use this method even if array dimensions are known.

To clarify in response to a comment, C99 allows passing of variable size arrays using the more intuitive syntax. However the standard isn't supported by Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler, which means that you can't use it for many practical purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.  The syntax you propose is certainly fine, but so is the OP's (analogous to, for example, `void foo(int array2d[5][6])`).  Personally, I prefer the form `void foo(int array2d[][6])`.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but so, define a 3D array like `char matrix[N][M][MAX_DIM]` is an error?

Comment: No, @PierpaoloDV, it isn't an error.  The subtlety here is that when that form is used to declare a function parameter, it actually declares a pointer of type `char (*)[M][MAX_DIM]`.  But that's exactly the correct type to receive an actual argument given by an expression whose type is `char[N][M][MAX_DIM]`, so everything works out as you might naively expect.

Comment: This is not about variable-length arrays.  The OP's `N`, `M`, and `MAX_DIM` are *macros* that expand to integer constants.  There are no VLAs here, and MSVC should not reject the OP's code on that basis.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So I should define _maxr_ not like `char maxr` but `char (*maxr)[M][MAX_DIM]` ?  And I just want to say that my coding level is very low, and my teacher is not really helpful. Everything you're saying me is really helpful.

Comment: No, @PierpaoloDV.  You are using your variable `maxr` to hold a single `char` drawn from your 3D array.  Its declaration is therefore correct as-is.

Comment: Sorry, @JohnBollinger. I do not understand where is my error, so.

Comment: That's reasonable, @PierpaoloDV, because I have not and do not claim that this answer or any of my comments on it address your problem.  Quite the opposite: I have primarily been critical of the answer.  To the extent that it makes any claim that your code is wrong, those particular claims appear to be inaccurate.